# .Net Core 5 Web Api - Swagger POST ok Xunit POST Error

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, webapi, xunit.net

I'm using XUnit to test my WebApi, GET requests are working ok. But when testing a POST through XUnit I received a 404 Bad Request while Swagger returns 200 OK

[image: Swagger 200 Ok]

[image: Swagger Request]

Teste

```
[Theory]
        [InlineData("POST")]
        public async Task ContestCreateTest(string method)
        {
            var _httpClient = new Setup().httpClient;

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(method), "/v1/Contest");

            var contestObject = new
            {
                title = "Concurso automatizado",
                description = "Concurso automatizado",
                submissionDeadLineInit = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1), TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("America/Sao_Paulo")).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'"),
                submissionDeadLineEnd = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(2), TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("America/Sao_Paulo")).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'"),
                ratingDeadLineInit = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(3), TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("America/Sao_Paulo")).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'"),
                ratingDeadLineEnd = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(4), TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("America/Sao_Paulo")).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'"),
                closingDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(5), TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("America/Sao_Paulo")).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'"),
                useDistritoRules = true,
                rules = ""
            };

            string contestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contestObject);

            request.Content = new StringContent(contestJson, Encoding.UTF8, "multipart/form-data");

            var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the image shows your API accepts form but you're sending data in json format.

```cs
var formDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    { new StringContent("Concurso automatizado", Encoding.UTF8), "title"},
    { new StringContent("Concurso automatizado", Encoding.UTF8), "description")},
    { new StringContent(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1), TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("America/Sao_Paulo")).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'", Encoding.UTF8), "submissionDeadLineInit" },
    ...
};

// Act
var response = await _client.PostAsync("/v1/Contest", formDataContent);
```

Comment: Perfect, I see this solution type in another forum but only unsing to upload image thank you for help. All Tests Passed with success!